# Showing Facebook Profile Picture After Login on the Redirected Page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I have a very basic problem. On my login page after the successful auth, i would like to show the logged in facebook user's profile picture as an avatar. I am redirecting from the login page to the TabsPage after auth.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-udvozoljuk',
  templateUrl: 'udvozoljuk.html',
})
export class UdvozoljukPage {

  facebook={
    loggedin: false,
    name: '',
    profilePicture: '',
    email: ''
  }

  constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad UdvozoljukPage');
  }

  loginWithFacebook(){
    this.fire.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
    .then( res=> {
      this.facebook.loggedin=true;
      this.facebook.name=res.user.displayName;
      this.facebook.email=res.user.email;
      this.facebook.profilePicture=res.user.photoURL;

      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    })
  }
```

On the HomePage (first tab in my Tabspage), i placed an avatar to the header:

```
<ion-avatar item-end>
        <img src="{{facebook.profilePicture}}">
    </ion-avatar>
```

The problem is that the facebook parameter is not defined and i have no idea how to get this working. I also tried navparams but no success. I imported the login page to the HomePage but i cant reach my facebook details.

Comment: I tought the tabspage causing the problem, so currently you see HomePage redirect,but same problem..

Comment: Is there data in the res.user.photoURL?  If it is a timing issue, you can display it with the async pipe on the page {{ (facebook.profilePicture | async) }}